# Regex word with all letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to write some regex to match word which is writen with any characters and highlights them using preg_replace

Example :

```
Search "cera" in "my sentence which contain cera, or Céra CErA or even cERa"
```

Return expected :

```
my sentence which contain <span class="highlight">cera</span>, or <span class="highlight">Céra</span> and <span class="highlight">CErA</span> or even <span class="highlight">cERa</span>"
```

Here is my regex but it doesn't work any ideas ?!

```
$string = preg_replace('\bcera\b\p{L}', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $text);
```

Comment: Make sure to use regex delimiter: `$string = preg_replace('/\bcera\b\p{L}/', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $text);`

Comment: thx for reply, does my regex is correct to perform what i want ? actually it doesn't work :/

Comment: What's the purpose of using `\p{L}`?

Comment: It s for Unicode Regular Expressions
Check out this link http://bit.ly/1FNd7I1

Comment: Very problematic. Why all letters? You said user input right? Is this an attempt to avoid escaping metachars? Also, the big problem is what _kind_ of boundary is to be matched or if boundary is even needed ?

Comment: And Regex word boundary is just a construct, not any reference to language at all !

Comment: I know what `\p{L}` does but `/\bcera\b\p{L}/` doesn't make much sense unless you clarify your requirements.

Comment: You need to check each word with a table to translate letters into a usable form. So you cannot use a regex for that. Use a regex to get the word, in the callback translate the word, if it matches, do the replacement.

Comment: What I want is explain below see @Jiremek comment 9min ago

Comment: I can't guess wich word will be search by the user inside search form :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function while return the regex search for looking for the value.
$text and $search set for demo

```
function txt_replace($search) {
    mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
    $match=Array("aáàâäåãAÁÀÂÄÅÃ","cçCÇ","eéèêëEÉÈÊË","iíìîïIÍÌÎÏ","nñNÑ","oóòôöõOÓÒÔÖÕ","uúùûüUÚÙÛÜ","yÿýYÝ","æÆ", "ɶŒœ");   
    foreach($match as $key => $value) {
            $search=mb_ereg_replace("([$value])", "[$value]*", $search);
    }
    return "({$search})";
}

$text="sàlut bonjour new york salut";
$search="sàlut";
$string=preg_replace('/'.txt_replace($search).'/i','<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $text);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$string = preg_replace('/(c[e|é|è]ra)/i{L}', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $text);`

I deleted \b i don't saw why that used.

Comment: Cera is just used as example, it can be any other word from user search

Comment: You whant to search for heho, hého and hèho when user say heho or hého for example.
Exact ?

Comment: That s right @Jiremek user search for heho regex should match with heho, hèho, Heho, HèhO and others combination. That s why I guess I need to use \p{L} or \p{Letter}: any kind of letter from any language.

Comment: See more in my new answer